# How to backup a Posterous blog?

Tags: posterous

Short of using 3rd party tools, is there a way of backing up a Posterous blog? If not, how do you suggest I do it (using 3rd party tools)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using their reading API 2.0 :

1. Login to your posterous account
2. Visit http://posterous.com/api/2/users/me/sites/primary/posts

You will receive a json file containing all your posts content.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, you can use this simple tool:
http://itunes.apple.com/cz/app/posterous-backup/id415889466?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

Since posterous is shutting down end of April, they now offer a way of backing up data. Login to your [Posterous account](http://posterous.com/) & click on the [backup](http://posterous.com/#backup) button to request a backup of your data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try http://justmigrate.com which basically uses api to move / backup your posterous to Tumblr.

This is also a work around for wordpress 15mb limit for importing posterous backup.